# How to propertly select items which are still loaded using promises?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have list of item IDs on page load:

```
var itemIds = [1, 5, 10, 11];
```

IDs are rendered into list and shown to user. I have function which loads detailed information about item, it returns Promise/A.

```
function loadInfo(id) { ... }
```

Loading of info for all items is initiated on page load:

```
val infos = {};
$.each(itemIds, function(i, id) { infos[id] = loadInfo(id); }
```

Now the problem itself.

When user clicks on item ID:

- if item info is loaded, info must be shown
- if item info is not yet loaded, it must be shown when it is loaded

Looks easy:

```
$('li').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('item-id');
    infos[id].then(function(info) { $('#info').text(info); });
});
```

But if user cliked on another item before current one is loaded, then I have to cancel handler on current item promise and schedule on new one.

How to properly do it?

I have several working solutions (like maintaining currentItemId variable and checking it in promise handler), but they are ugly. Should I look to reactive programming libraries instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kriomant,

I guess there's a number of ways you could code this. Here's one :

```
var INFOS = (function(){
    var infoCache = {},
        promises = {},
        fetching = null;

    var load = function(id) {
        if(!promises[id]) {
            promises[id] = $ajax({
                //ajax options here
            }).done(function(info){
                infoCache[id] = info;
                delete promises[id];
            });
        }
        return promises[id];
    }

    var display = function(id, $container) {
        if(fetching) {
            //cancel display (but not loading) of anything latent.
            fetching.reject();
        }
        if(infoCache[id]) {
            //info is already cached, so simply display it.
            $container.text(infoCache[id]);
        }
        else {
            fetching = $.Deferred().done(function() {
                $container.text(infoCache[id]);
            });
            load(id).done(fetching.resolve);
        }
    }
    return {
        load: load,
        display: display
    };
})();
```

As you will see, all the complexity is bundled in the namespace `INFOS`, which exposes two methods; `load` and `display`.

Here's how to call the methods :

```
$(function() {
    itemIds = ["p7", "p8", "p9"];

    //preload
    $.each(itemIds, function(i, id) { INFOS.load(id); });

    //load into cache on first click, then display from cache.
    $('li').on('click', function() {
        var id = $(this).data('item-id');
        INFOS.display(id, $('#info'));
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dEXUr/1/)** (with simulated ajax)

The tricks here are :

- to cache the infos, indexed by id
- to cache active jqXHR promises, indexed by id
- to display info from cache if previously loaded ...
- ... otherwise, each time info is requested, create a Deferred associated with display of the info, that can be resolved/rejected independently of the corresponding jqXHR.

Comment: Ok, this solution is in fact similar to what I use and it is, as I said, ugly. However, since this is the only answer and it is technically correct I accept it.

Comment: Maybe someone will come along with something less "ugly" but, like me, they will probably struggle with definition on that point. Ugliness is just like beauty - it's in the eye of the beholder.